# Including methods on to_json call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, paperclip, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to render a json from an `ActiveRecord::Base` object, including `paperclip`'s methods.

```
> i = Model.last
> i.to_json methods: :picture
=> # Successful output
```

Problem is, I need `.picture.url(:tiny)` and `to_json methods: 'picture.url(:tiny)'` doesn't work. **Is there a way to make `to_json` work or I'll have to work this around other way?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your picture model, create a method called `picture_avatar`

```
def tiny_avatar
  picture.url(:tiny)
end
```

then use that method to pass to `to_json`

```
i.to_json methods: :tiny_avatar
```